# Prepend drag icon to each form element

Tags: 8, forms

I am building a configuration form with a few sortable elements. I know, you can build a table using builtin Drupal draggable functionality (**drupal_attach_tabledrag**), but it's a bit too complicated for my task.

I am saving new order of elements inside a hidden input field value using Jquery UI **Sortable** function and dynamically set **#weights** in form elements:

```
    $weights = $config->get('sort_order');
    parse_str($weights, $weights);


    $form['el1'] = [
        '#type' => 'checkbox',
        '#title' => 'Title1',
        '#default_value' => $config->get('el1'),
        '#weight' => $weights['el1']
    ];

    $form['el2'] = [
        '#type' => 'checkbox',
        '#title' => 'Title2',
        '#default_value' => $config->get('el2'),
        '#weight' => $weights['el2']
    ];
```

Elements are draggable and sorting works fine. The only difficulty I have is prepending an icon to each element so that others could use that icon to drag elements up and down (just like Drupal does in a lot of configuration UIs).

I know you can create custom elements using **#markup** with an image tag inside it, or some div with image background. But adding custom markup to each element is problematic for several reasons:

1. I'll have to write different names for each markup separately. For example if I have a markup element:

   ```
   $form['drag-icon'] = [
       '#type' => '#markup',
       '#markup'=> '<p class="drag-icon"></p>'
   ];
   ```

its name is **drag-icon** and to prepend it to another element, I'd have to use a different name each time (this is horrible).

2. Although it can be aligned well with the element using css, dragging on that icon, breaks the line while moving it up/down.
3. Would have to write this mark up manually for each element.

I also tried using a template file for this form, but among other things, I couldn't keep track of sort order inside it so easily as in **buildForm()** function using **#weight**.

I wrote a lot of explanations to show what I have tried.

I just want a simple method to append an icon to each element of the form to achieve something like this:

[image]

Comment: Why not just use css?

Comment: @Clive, As you know, by default, each form element consists of a label and a field wrapped around by a div. Yes, using css is easy. But for that I need another element inside the div, placed before the label and input, so that I could use a background-image on it and then float it left. Is there a simple way do this?

Comment: Just use a `::before` selector on the element you want it before, position absolute (negative left), with position relative on the original element

Answer (score 0):

I want to implement this dragging functionality in Drupal 8,
may i know how you achieve draggable functionality in that or can you share the code

Comment: There were two ways I managed to accomplish making elements draggable: 1. Using Drupal's  **drupal_attach_tabledrag** and 2. Making form elements draggable using JQuery UI's draggable component: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: As for sharing the code, I was doing all that for educational purposes and I've long lost it, sorry. I never got back to it.